# Wpf Show Frame's Content(Wpf Page) at Design Time In IDE(Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a frame control and it's source set to a page in xaml like this:

```
Source="/Myapp;component/MyFolder/Mypage.xaml"
```

Frame control shows the page when i run the application. But i want to see page displaying at frame control at design time.(Visual Studio 2017). It only shows a text like this: (/Myapp;component/MyFolder/Mypage.xaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for a single page in design time.

Make sure you have the Blend namespace defined in your root xaml element.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Then add the `d:DesignInstace` attribute to your `Frame`.

```
<Frame d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MyPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"  
       Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Then add something like this to your to the constructor where your `Frame` is hosted, after the `InitializeComponent` call.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _frame.Content = null;
    _frame.NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Visible;
    _frame.Source = new Uri("/Wpf;component/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

That should allow you to navigate with the `Source` property normally.

Comment: İ just tried it, now i can see the page in design time, but i can't navigate that page using frame.source at runtime.

Comment: Not sure using the `Source` property is the best way to go, so I edited my answer to remove that part. How are you navigating the frame pages?

Comment: Normally i'm using the source property to navigate pages. But after using your xaml code, i can't navigate with source property anymore.