# MVVMLight Display Page in Frame during Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying get the nice design time experience that Laurent Bugnion talks about in some of his videos.  This is a WPF application in VS2017 Community on a Win7 machine.

In a Window, a FRAME control binds to a URI.  Source="{Binding FrameUri, Mode=TwoWay}"  The program is working during runtime but during design time, I have the following link to the URL that shows up in the frame (see first image).

The tricky thing to point out is that the MainPage has its MainViewModel and the IntroPage also its own viewmodel (IntroViewModel).

DESIGN TIME IMAGE
[image]

RUNTIME IMAGE

[image]

I'm guessing that the Intro Page is not instantiated during design time, but not sure how to do it.  I tried to add a design time line to the Frame xaml, but that didn't work:  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:PageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

I also tried adding Path= IntroPageViewModel in XAML and that didn't work either.

I have the code for the program here:  https://github.com/floppydisk525/MvvmLight_WPF_Frame_Nav/tree/NavTest

Here's code:
APP.XAML FILE

```html
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IntroViewModel}">
            <v:IntroPage/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>    
</Application>
```

FRAME code:

```html
<Frame  x:Name="MainFrameDS" Source="{Binding FrameUri, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="109,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258"/>
```

FRAME URI PROPERTY:

```
        public const string FrameUriPropertyName = "FrameUri";

    private Uri _frameUri;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the FrameUri property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public Uri FrameUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _frameUri;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(FrameUriPropertyName, ref _frameUri, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_frameUri.ToString(), "_frameUri");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FrameUri.ToString(), "FrameUri");
        }
    }
```

FROM ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public static readonly Uri IntroPageUri = new Uri("/IntroPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    public static readonly Uri MiddlePageUri = new Uri("/MiddlePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    public static readonly Uri LastPageUri = new Uri("/LastPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        var NavigationService = new NavigationService();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IntroViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MiddleViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LastViewModel>();

`#if DEBUG
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            var instance = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IntroViewModel>();
        }
 `#endif
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that the Intro Page is not instantiated during design
>   time, but not sure how to do it. I tried to add a design time line to
>   the Frame xaml, but that didn't work: d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance
>   viewModels:PageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

The xaml part alone isn't enough.
To Instantiate your view models during design time you should use *"ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic"* in your ViewModelLocator.

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
}
else
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();         
}
```

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx) seems to be a nice article if you need more information.

Comment: That was an excellent article by Laurent no less...  The implementation problem that I'm struggling with is that the URI is binding to the source property of the frame (that works), but the frame shows the text of the URI link and not the page.  I'm not sure if this is a datatemplate or page instantiation issue.  I'm not sure how to link the URI to a static (?) instance of the page. I did try the #DEBUG from the article with      var instance = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IntroViewModel>();  But, what do I set instance to in the mainviewmodel?  Just confused.

Comment: @FloppyDisk Since its working at runtime and since you already mapped your IntroPage to your IntroViewModel with a DataTemplate I think that at DesignTime the IntroViewModel  isn't instantiated (hence why it just showed the name of the URI). That's why i suggested you should maybe check for "IsInDesignModeStatic" before registering your IntroViewModel in your ViewModelLocator. Just a guess though.

Comment: I updated the viewmodelLocator code in the initial post (at the end) with what I tried and it didn't work.   Somehow I'm missing the syntax.

Comment: @FloppyDisk Maybe it's the frame itself that needs to be specified. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294210/wpf-show-frames-contentwpf-page-at-design-time-in-idevisual-studio-2017) in another post. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Damn seeing just now that you already tried that. Weird the view model is instantiated/registered and the frame is also configured for design time data. Only guess i have left is that the datatemplate has to also be configured for design time data (like the frame), but honestly i don't know how the syntax would be (or if it would be correct^^).

Comment: I have tried the line from the link you provided: **<Frame d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MyPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"  
       Content="{Binding}"/>**  I can't seem to get the Type=local:MyPage to work.  I try to set it like this:   **d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=v:IntroPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}**     The v: is defined as:  **xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MvvmLight_WPF_Frame_Nav"**   I also get an warning AD0001 that ends with, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."       I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Seem to be closer.

Comment: @FloppyDisk Sorry for the late answer. Since you already used the namespace for your datatemplate it should be correct. I found something regarding the solution that you tested. If you already wrote things in the code behind constructor u can try using [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29874.aspx) approach i found, where you just return after InitializeComponent if you are in design mode.

Comment: Link taken from msdn forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6142641f-6643-4b04-8895-0c76157474a0/xaml-designer-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?forum=wpf). It may be that `_frame.Content = null;
    _frame.NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Visible;
    _frame.Source = new Uri("/Wpf;component/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);` from the example may cause the problem.

Comment: I rebuilt the application with only the mainwindow and Frame.  Was trying to eliminate any issues that might cause the program to hang up.  I went back and tried the _frame.source = etc...  link.  I tried it in code behind and that didn't work.  I think part of the difficulty is that I used the 'source' property of the frame and the source property requires a URI.  So, I don't set the frame equal to an instantiated page, but to a URI that needs to 'point' to the page (not sure I said that correctly).       I tried Paul Stovell's _mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1()); didn't work.

Comment: Hm yeah maybe it just doesn't work with the Source property/ URI. Unfortunately i am kind of out of ideas. Last thing i can give you is [another mvvm light approach to navigation](http://www.joeljoseph.net/navigation-between-pages-using-mvvm-light-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp/) that probably shows something at design time(since it doesn't use the URI). The example also uses the NavigationService and Pages so you should be able to use it for a Frame like in the example of Paul Stovell(which i guess was [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation)). No guarantee though^^.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a solution, albeit with a new question.

I was trying different things, most recently from this [stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294210/wpf-show-frames-contentwpf-page-at-design-time-in-idevisual-studio-2017).  I have a working solution on github [MvvmLight_Frame_DesignTime](https://github.com/floppydisk525/MvvmLight_Frame_DesignTime) with a more detailed write-up and pictures.

### Solution

The following lines were first added in the MainWindow.xaml file.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MvvmLight_Frame_DesignTime"
```

Then the Frame control had the d: designtime code added along with the Content Property.

```
<Frame HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="25,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=v:IntroPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
    Content ="{Binding}"                 
    Source="{Binding FrameUri}"/>
```

### Notes

What's important to note is that I don't instantiate a Frame or Page control from the Viewmodel code or code behind like the above example on stack overflow. This makes the solution very simple and little code.

### Question

Is it ok to use the Source & Content property for the Frame?  Could this be done differently?
The way that I think it works is in design mode the DesignInstance is instantiated with the Type=v:IntroPage and is binded to the Content property.  During runtime, since the IntroPage type isn't created and the MainViewModel  FrameUri property binds to the Frame Source, then that takes precedence.  Seems to work, not sure what issues could arise from it.